# What's the "height:auto" trick to sliding a div down

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, yui3

I have an application that displays a simple <ul> list of projects. When the user clicks on a new "Category", I'd like to replace the list of projects with a **new** list of projects.

I'm open to additional transition suggestions but what I've started with is --

1. Shrink or *slide* up and remove the existing project list node
2. Dynamically (Javascript DOM methods) create a new project list with a height of 0
3. Attach the new list to the page and expand or *slide* it down

I am using Yahoo's YUI3 library which doesn't yet have native 'slideup' or 'slidedown' methods so I'm simulating them. I can easily simulate "slideup" by executing a simple animation that sets the height=0 but I'm having trouble simulating the "slidedown" method since I don't know the final height of the <ul> list (I am dynamically building).

I'd like the height to be appropriate - ie: behave just like normal html - which means I want "height:auto" ... but YUI3 cannot animate/transition the CSS property from height:0 to height:auto. It needs an float value.

I've looked at a few Javascript libraries that can slide divs up and down (jQuery) and appears to simply save off the original value for height - but that would be "auto" ... which wouldn't work. Maybe it is calculating the actual height in someway first?

Can anyone walk through the best way to do this? Would I need to manually calculate the height as I build the list ... and then set its style to height:0, and then animate it to the calculated height, and then set its style to height:auto just to be sure it is left in a good state? If so, what is a cross-browser way to do that?

Thanks,
-Luther

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more or less what you're looking for.  The trick is to have two nested div's.  The outer one controls the actual height, and the inner one is used to calculate the natural height.  After the animation is finished the outer div reverts to "auto" if it is expanded, so that you can dynamically add more list elements.

This was shamelessly adapted from a [JQuery blog post](http://blog.mandalatv.net/2010/09/animate-css-width-or-height-to-auto-in-jquery).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<title>Animate to Auto</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
.inner {background:#ccc;height:auto;overflow:hidden;}
.inner ol{margin:0;}
.box{height:0px;overflow:hidden;}
</style> <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
        src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.2.0/build/yui/yui-min.js">
</script>
</head> 
<body> 
<button class="btn">Toggle Height</button> 
<div class="box"> 
<div class="inner"> 
  <ol> 
    <li>Bashful</li> 
    <li>Doc</li> 
    <li>Dopey</li> 
    <li>Grumpy</li> 
    <li>Happy</li> 
    <li>Sleepy</li> 
    <li>Sneezy</li> 
  </ol> 
</div> 
</div>
OTHER STUFF HERE

<script> 
YUI().use('node', 'event', 'anim', function(Y) {

    var heightAnim = new Y.Anim({
      node: Y.one('.box'),
      to: {
        height: 0
      }
    });

    heightAnim.on('end', function (e) {
      var box = heightAnim.get('node');
      if (parseInt(box.getStyle('height')) > 0) {
        box.setStyle('height', 'auto');
      }
    });

    Y.one('.btn').on('click', function(e){
      var box = this.get('node');
      var inner = box.one('.inner');
      var boxH = box.getStyle('height');
      if (boxH === 'auto') {
        box.setStyle('height',inner.getStyle('height'));
        this.set('to', {height: 0});
        this.run();
      } else {
        this.set('to', {height: parseInt(inner.getStyle('height'))});
        this.run();
      }
    },heightAnim);

});
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about setting a min-height property with an overflow to visible?

Comment: I wonder how would that play with elements underneath? Will it properly push them down as the project list extends to 200 names?

Comment: Yep, I believe it would... But I would set display:block to make sure :)